# Does Vertex AI Search allow sorting by date?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vertex-ai-search

Google is sunsetting the site-restrict custom search API and attempting to replace it with Vertex AI search. A core feature of the CSE search functionality is sorting results by most recent.

Does Vertex AI Search have any capacity for querying by time sorting? I haven't seen any documentation relating to how to do this if it's available.

If it isn't available, it's sorely needed, particularly for datastores indexed over websites for website search.